# Will HTML5 completely remove the use of backend languages?

Tags: html

I keep hearing about HTML5 applications. When they say that, do they mean applications that are built using HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript only and without the help of MySQL, PHP and other backend tools?

Comment: Not at all, you still need them

Comment: Read the SO http://stackoverflow.com/faq, especially the part stating "ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"HTML 5 Application" is whishy-washy marketing speak. It might mean something that stands alone (probably using non-HTML 5 APIs such as [web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#storage)), it might mean something that just uses a little bit of HTML 5.

Certainly you still need a server if any data needs to travel beyond the browser (e.g. to share data with other people / devices, back data up on the cloud, get news feeds, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Most of the web applications are 3 tier that means heart of application is Business Logic. And I don't think any Business will get ready to write business logic in HTML for security reason and there are many more such reason like code reliability,maintainability come into picture. So no one can remove use of back end languages.